# python savetxt. The number of save data is incorrect

Tags: python

When I use the function savetxt to save 614400 complex symbols, the total number of the data saved is always less than 614400.
When I use the function savetxt to save 614400 real-numbers, the total number of the data saved is sometimes less than 614400, sometimes equal to 614400. Unstable.

If use the write function, the saving speed is too slow.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: Any code available, so one can see what you did or tried?

Comment: You need to add tags or specify that this is numpy. That isn’t assumed. Python has all kinds of uses besides data science, and even in data science there are other packages besides numpy (e.g. pandas).

Answer (score 0):

This method works. I generate an array of complex numbers and then saving the text file takes 1.66 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import time

n = 614400
arr = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, int(n/2)) + 1.j * np.random.uniform(-1, 1, int(n/2))

save_time = time.time()

np.savetxt("out.txt", arr.view(float))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - save_time))
```